# visual basic .net Function have error return

Tags: vb.net

So the error is BC42353 ( Function ValidateInputFields doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you missing a Return statement? ) I'm getting this error twice. I put exclamation points on the lines that it says the errors are on.

```
Private Function CekBarcode(sID As String, cost As Long, price As Long, ByVal vslist As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Try
        For i = 1 To vslist.Rows.Count - 1
            If sID = vslist.Rows(i - 1).Cells(1).Value Then
                '  CekBarcode = True
                vslist.Rows(i - 1).Cells(10).Value = vslist.Rows(i - 1).Cells(10).Value + 1
                Return True
                Exit For
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You're starting very badly with `Dim i As Long`: Cells indexers cannot be of Type `Long`. You need `Return False` after the Try/Catch block (or rewrite this procedure). -- I suggest to set `Option Strict On` and see what happens there.

Comment: Your code makes little sense. You have an `Exit For` immediately after a `Return` statement, for one thing. You also have a loop and an `If...Else` block inside it with a `Return` statement in both blocks. That means that there's no w3ay that you can possibly perform more than one iteration of that loop. I suggest that you do what you should have in the first place and work out the logic first, then write code to implement that logic. The code you have doesn't implement any logic that you could possibly want.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that that would be a warning rather than an error. The issue is that you may never enter that loop, i.e. if there are not more than one row in the collection, so you'd never hit one of your `Return` statements. It may be that, in practice, that would never happen but the compiler can't read your mind. In theory, it's possible for that method to complete without an explicit `Return` so you need to fix that to clear the warning. In future, consider all the possible outcomes and not just the one(s) you intend.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Private Function CekBarcode(sID As String, cost As Long, price As Long, ByVal vslist As DataGridView) As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        'maybe to add this below line /check is there more than one row in grid
        If vslist.Rows.Count < 2 Then Return result
        Try
            For i = 1 To vslist.Rows.Count - 1
                If sID = vslist.Rows(i - 1).Cells(1).Value.ToString() Then
                    '  CekBarcode = True
                    vslist.Rows(i - 1).Cells(10).Value = vslist.Rows(i - 1).Cells(10).Value + 1
                    result = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Catch
            result = False
        End Try
        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: The `Exit Function` means that there will still be a path that doesn't return a value.  Perhaps you meant `Return result` instead?

Comment: @Craig Yes, your right. Fast typing. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to use either `cost` or `price` and you probably want to specify `ByRef` on the DGV to update it.

```
Private Function CekBarcode(sID As String, ByRef vslist As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In vslist.Rows
            If row.Item(1).Equals(sID) Then
                row.Item(10) = CInt(row.Item(10)) + 1
                result = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next row
    Catch
        'result = False ' Not required - result is only changed within the If
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

Or you can dispense with the `result` variable and `Exit For`:

```
Private Function CekBarcode(sID As String, ByRef vslist As DataGridView) As Boolean
    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In vslist.Rows
            If row.Item(1).Equals(sID) Then
                row.Item(10) = CInt(row.Item(10)) + 1
                Return True
            End If
        Next row
    Catch
        ' Fall through to return False
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```